# Is the discussion of truth and perception circular in reasoning?

Tags: existentialism, heidegger, realism, appearance-and-actuality

Can the cliche, *"Perception is reality"* be incorrect in that (objective) reality is a version of the (subjective) truth, and this version of truth is a form of perception?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This cliche is usually not used in the context of philosophy at all. It doesn't mean perception is literally reality. It is typically used to say public perception of success (or failure) of a venture can cause the actual success or failure of the venture.

Comment: oh wow thanks for that. i had no idea what was being asked @causative

Comment: Psychology Today says no: [Perception Is Not Reality](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-power-prime/201908/perception-is-not-reality). However, entrenched perception of something in a certain way does create a psychological or social reality of its own, which is what the cliche most commonly alludes to, see e.g. [false consciousness](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-1-4614-5583-7_523).

Answer (score 0):

So, many people come to this site and use the word 'reality' without much reflection on what it means. In fact, the term is polysemous and many of the paradoxes and contradictions generated around 'reality' disappear when one takes the time to clarify what is meant. For reality, you will often hear discussion in several contexts: personal reality, social reality, and physical reality are three prominent examples. Just characterizing reality as subjective or objective will quickly fall into discussions about [intersubjectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersubjectivity). Let's lay out a few claims.

**Personal reality** is generally taken to mean one's [phenomenological experience](https://iep.utm.edu/phenom/). In this sense, perception IS reality because, if in the spirit of Kant, one believes that one is constrained by the experience of one's mind, then it is impossible to know the [Ding-an-sich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing-in-itself). We can continue to approach knowledge of the [noumena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noumenon), but can never quite achieve it living in a world of ontological ambiguity. Let us call this REALITY<sub>1</sub>.

**Social reality** is taken to be a collection of individuals who all agree with reality. Searle devotes his efforts to this in the *Social Construction of Reality* and *Making the Social World*. These are related to the sociological notions of [social constructivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_constructivism) and [social constructionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_constructionism). A philosophical classic in this topic is also [Berger and Luckman's *The Social Construction of Reality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Social_Construction_of_Reality). Let us call this REALITY<sub>2</sub>.

**Physical reality** is in broad strokes what is meant by the idea that we inhabit an [objective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjectivity_and_objectivity_(philosophy)), external world which conforms to a set of rules formerly known as the [Laws of Nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_law). It's the idea that no one is free to deny gravity but not escape the consequences of it. Daniel Dennnett has a shiny word [heterophenomological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterophenomenology) that moves in the direction of an [intersubjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersubjectivity) understanding of physical reality. Let us call this REALITY<sub>3</sub>.

Now that we've tackled the popular senses of the term (in perhaps the order that people are likely to experience thinking about them), let's have another look at your question.

> Can the cliche, "Perception is reality" be incorrect in that (objective) reality is a version of the (subjective) truth, and this version of truth is a form of perception?

So, now we can say that "perception is reality" is absolutely meaningful as "perception is REALITY<sub>1</sub>", since on the phenomenological view, one cannot directly experience being others or have impartial perspective of the external world. But, the claim "perception is REALITY<sub>3</sub>" is also quite arguable these days, since in fact, with REALITY<sub>3</sub>, many famous philosophers have taken to leave 'reality' somewhat behind and now engage in discussions about [antirealism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-realism).

In philosophy of science, this sort of position is known as [instrumentalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentalism) and is an outgrowth of the failure of [logical positivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_positivism) to purge metaphysical values from scientific theory. [Theory-ladenness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory-ladenness) essentially maintains that there is no objective observation at all, a point interestingly affirmed by quantum mechanics where it is the observer that determines if [light is a wave or a particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality).

So, for philosophers, who often draw fastidiously fine distinctions, your question doesn't have a canonical answer, but rather a range of responses depending on the philosophers in question. Bas van Fraassen has his [constructive empiricism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_empiricism). Searle has distinctly realist views since he rejects the representational theory of mind and Cartesian duality. Wilfrid Sellars attacks sense data as an empirical experience by labeling them the [Myth of the Given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilfrid_Sellars#Empiricism_and_the_philosophy_of_mind). [John McDowell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McDowell) rejects "bald naturalism" and is a [conceptualist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptualism). [George Lakoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Lakoff) puts forth his embodied realism.

**So, the safest thing to say is that "perception is reality" is not so much correct or incorrect, true or false, but adequate or inadequate depending on your definitions of 'perception' and 'reality', and that there is a plurality of well-regarded philosophical positions on this sort of broad claim.** (Which isn't quite satisfying if you expect there is one, true answer, but is rather typical of how philosophy actually functions in the real world.)

Comment: Thank your clarifications, J.D.  Let me restate, given the above definitions: 
Is the cliche, "Perception is reality" circular reasoning if the reality we are taking about is **physical reality**, and that reality is taken to be the truth. However, that truth is itself is subjective, which means _it is perceived to be the truth_, subject to the physical reality of someone’s situation. (I ask the question, because my latest novel—in progress—has a character who cannot tell the difference between the physical reality of his social media ratings and his perception of them.)

Comment: I'd say that physical reality is always a collection of truths. An electron has this mass. The color of an apple is usually red or green. Iron rusts outdoors. Etc. Each of those truths is derived from sensory observation and experience directly and indirectly. To say "difference between the physical reality of ratings and perception" is to say that a character sees one thing (You have 100% approval) when the display says another (You have 60% approval.) In the extreme, hallucinations. More typically, [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias)...

Comment: A person subconsciously ignores physical observations that would lead them to conclude something other than what they want to see. This isn't a problem with seeing physical reality literally, but making sense of the conceptualization of it. In this sense we are talking about personal reality. The difference in fiction can be illustrated between Walter Mitty who actively constructs a fictional world, and your average biased media viewer who ignores media that disconfirms their beliefs.

Comment: In both cases, I would say the problem is circular because once a belief is established, it tends to act as a filter about other beliefs. So, yes, there's a circularity problem with a heavily biased epistemology. The next belief is usually derived from the previous belief.

Comment: Your point about confirmation bias is well taken. I conclude from this that to change the cycle of escalating biases a new/different fundamental truth must become evident and/or dominant. (This would be a turning point in a fictional narrative.)

Comment: Well, I'd say that it depends on the nature of the narrative. In a tragedy, the fatal flaws of a protagonist might lead the plot to a climax where everything can end well only if the protagonist sees the truth, but then fails to. Human beings are remarkably resistant to changing their minds. Here in Chicago, Festinger wrote about a ufo religion in the 50's where when the apocalypse failed to materialize, it did not deter belief. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Prophecy_Fails See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delusion.

Comment: And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalization_(psychology)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are playing with words.

It is obvious that what we see or hear is happening in the mind, but we generally accept this as the reflection of something. This reflection is called *perception* and this something is called *reality*.

Whether this reality is *true* and whether it is *objective* or *subjective* is a matter of interpretation. But, in order for the interpretation to have a meaning, you need a context.